# An ImageIcon not even used is affecting my JFrame/JPanel. Why?

Tags: java, swing, imageicon

I hope this isn’t a stupid first question; I can’t seem to find an answer anyway.

I have this `JFrame` constructor where a `JPanel` is added to the `JFrame`. The `JPanel` paints a `Rectangle` in the `JFrame`, and that’s fine. **However**, if I add an `ImageIcon` object as in the code below (for later use), the rectangle isn’t painted. It does appear if I resize the window though.

One solution is to put the `setVisible(true)` as the last line, or to instantiate the `ImageIcon` above the constructor, but I really want to understand this. It doesn’t make sense to me that an object not even used can cause this behaviour. Thanks.

```
public class AJFrame extends JFrame {

    ImageIcon ii;

    public AJFrame() {
        setSize(400,400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);

        ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("Untitled.png");

        JPanel jp = new JPanel() {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                g.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
            }
        };

        add(jp);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AJFrame jf = new AJFrame();
    }
}
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html

Comment: @JBNizet - I don't follow. Care to be more specific?

Comment: The very first instruction of your program violates the rules defined in the page I linked to, and that might very well be the cause of your problem.

Comment: @JBNizet - The rules of the single page you linked to, or the rules on somewhere on the trail? 

I assume to are talking about " All other Swing component methods must be invoked from the event dispatch thread. Programs that ignore this rule may function correctly most of the time, but are subject to unpredictable errors that are difficult to reproduce.". 

It's confusing to me though as I have never heard about this before even though having worked with the swing-package quite a lot. But thx.

Comment: Read the whole trail. But the page I specifically linked to shows you how to initialize a JFrame from the main() method. You're not respecting this idiom in your code, which means that the JFrame is created in the main thread instead of being created in the event dispatch thread.

Comment: I think I got it now. Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All actions within a frame should be done in the EDT (Event Dispatching Thread) of Swing. Therefore the right way to start your frame is

```
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new AJFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
});
```

So maybe it all comes down to the wrong start of your frame.

The main routine of a Java program is not started within the EDT. All Swing actions that are not within the EDT could produce strange refresh/visibility issues.

Here is the complete sourcecode:

```
public class AJFrame extends JFrame {

    ImageIcon ii;

    public AJFrame() {
        setSize(400, 400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        //setVisible(true);

        //ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("Untitled.png");
        JPanel jp = new JPanel() {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                g.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
            }
        };

        add(jp);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new AJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on exactly what you mean by, `"ImageIcons are loaded in a different thread as well."`, as it is not very clear to me. It looks to me like in the OP's code everything is done in one single thread.

Comment: You are right. It had nothing tp do with the question and was unclear so I removed it. Thx for the hint.

Comment: One of the things the textbook doesn't tell you until later, or how should I interpret this newly found information? Anyways, I added this  to my code and it caused my frame to constantly refresh, so it didn't do much good, but thx.

Comment: Then you did it not include in the right way. I added to my answer the complete source code. Maybe you forgot to remove the setVisible within your AJFrame constructor. I have no constant refresh.

Comment: Having no previous experience with EventQueue, I place that code in the constructor, so thanks for clarifying. I'll try to find some more info on this. Thanks!

Btw, what do you call the practice of overriding a method of an object that you create in another class? You do it with new Runnable() and I do it with the new JPanel. I found it in a book and it's the first time I've used it. I would like to read more about that :)